# How Can I Fill Dataset with Values from 2 Tables with an Inner Join Query

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have 2 tables 1Tbl_purchasemaster1 and 1Tbl_purchasesub1  and a query like:

```
SELECT  Tbl_PurchaseMaster.dtPurchaseDate,Tbl_PurchaseMaster.vaSupplierName,
    Tbl_PurchaseSub.vaItemCode,Tbl_PurchaseSub.intQuantity 
FROM Tbl_PurchaseMaster 
INNER JOIN Tbl_PurchaseSub 
ON 
dbo.Tbl_PurchaseMaster.intPurchaseMasterID = dbo.Tbl_PurchaseSub.intPurchaseMasterID 
where dtPurchaseDate between  '" + dtfr + "'and'" + dtto 
    + "' dtfr=datefrom and dtto=dateto..
```

How can I fill these values into Dataset? After filling it, I want to show it in Crystal Reports. please help

Answer (score 0):

If you have the join already done, SQL returns effectively one table and you can put that into the DataSet as a DataTable.

You could also query each table individually into two DataTables in the DataSet and then add a relationship.

There is no provision in a DataSet to take the result of an SQL join and split it into multiple DataTables.

Comment: really thanks for your answer .already i joined 2 tables Tbl_Purchasemaster and Tbl_Purchasesub.which table is effectively returns?would you please explain second method you mentioned above?

Comment: When I say effectively one table, I mean it returns a set of rows with fields.  Here is an example of how to fill DataTables and create a DataRelation:  http://csharp.net-informations.com/dataset/dataset-relations.htm